Please help me identify this connector from the 80s
I'm here after spending a several hours at https://connectorbook.com/ and while I learned some terms that describe my mystery connector, I haven't been able to determine a make and model. I hoping y'all can directly identify this connector or add more details that I might use in my search.
From The Electronic Connector Book, I learned that this connector would probably be categorized as board-to-board or single-wall one-row, but I haven't found any images that match yet.
Perhaps the most unique trait is how the connectors make contact -- it's like an edge cross lap joint in woodworking. Anyway, here are measurements and photos. Please let me know whether you want more information.
Measurements

application: English industrial motor controller from the late 80s
32 contacts
one row
2.54 mm pitch
one wall
no bumps or latches
101.6 mm long
17 mm wide
7.4 mm tall
88.5 mm spacing for top-facing mounting holes
95.2 mm spacing for front-facing mounting holes

Photos

From above and behind

From above and afore

Detail on pins

From the front

Complementary connector


The pins are spade-shaped with a slot down the center. The two connectors press together with the spades rotated 90 degrees from each other.

It looks like the connector would plug into a rotated version of itself, and you have a horizontal and a vertical example.  Is this right?

Yes, that's correct. All the photos are from the same connector except that last one, which is a vertically oriented one on the "main board". I took the most photos of the "plug in" board, which is a horizontally oriented connector. Both connectors have the "one wall" feature and only connect in one position.

If it's 2,54mm pitch then there are countless replacements. Unless you are pedantically concerned about authenticity (because you work at a museum or something), just rip the damn ting off and replace it with a header strip or box header.

I remember those hermaphroditic contacts, but from well before the 1980s. ca. 1970, maybe. They are associated with EDAC now.

No idea if they still make the ones you show there.

Thank you! They still use that contact design, but whether I can find a seller for these is a task for tomorrow-me  My estimate of the vintage is from the manufacturing codes on the ICs, but the connectors have no (uncovered) markings or identifiers that I can see.

@user1635886 This is the closest one to yours that EDAC still lists. It's not yours, though. Yours must be obsolete.

Thank you  It looks like it's time for some creative approaches!
